# How to stop the running application inside docker?

Tags: docker

Here is my docker file that builds my cpp application using meson and ninja.
Afterwards, it starts executing my application.
Now, I want to stop my application. How can I do so?
I have tried giving STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM in the docker file but it didn't help.
Here is my docker file -

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim as base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    vim \
    nano \
    tree \
    git \
    locales \
    locales-all \
    ssh \
    python3 \
    less \
    net-tools \
    iputils-ping \
    gcc  \
    g++  \
    meson \
    ninja-build 

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN mkdir -p /app

CMD ["cd /app && meson builddir && cd builddir && ninja docker_test && ./docker_test"]
```

STOPSIGNAL SIGTERM

Here is my cpp application.

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
    while(1)            
    {
       std::cout<<"Hello Docker"<<std::endl;
       usleep(10000000);
    }
  return 0;

}
```

Here is my meson.build file.

```
project('demo', 'cpp')
executable('docker_test',  'docker_test.cpp')
```

How do I stop my application?

$docker run  --rm -ti   --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/,target=/app

I am trying to stop the hello docker program using ctrl + x but it still continues to work and I can't stop it.

Comment: Your Dockerfile doesn't seem to `COPY` the application code in; you can `RUN` the build steps so they don't get repeated every time you start the application; and you don't need the `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper.  That would reduce the startup to just `CMD ["./docker_test"]` which would not involve the shell wrapper, and might run more predictably.

Comment: (In the context of a C application, think of a Dockerfile as not unlike a Makefile.)

Comment: @DavidMaze - You can see that I am mounting my local storage. This is essential for the cases where the user uses bitbucket with ssh keys. Thus, you cannot copy a big project from your local to docker. Also, once copied, it needs ssh keys. Thus, you cannot deploy the docker build system to anybody. The idea here is to give a docker build so that users can build their project without worrying about environment. Finally, run the app on the docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container is running `docker_test` script as the init process or process with `PID` of 1. What this means is that as long as this process is alive, the container is alive (in `RUNNING` state).

When you want to stop the application, in this case, it is as good as stopping the container.

```
docker stop <container_name/container_id>
```

Notice, however, that you are running the command `docker run --rm -ti --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/,target=/app`, if the container is stopped, it will be remove automatically.

Not sure what your use case is but here is what I suggest:

```
# Run a container with bash command
docker run --rm -it --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/,target=/app <docker_image_name> bash

# Execute the script inside the container
cd /app && meson builddir && cd builddir && ninja docker_test && ./docker_test

# Stop the application as and when you like by using Ctrl + C
```

Comment: it can't be true my entry point is /bin/bash so bin/bash should be pid 1 and not my app. I don't want to get inside container and run those commands like cd /app ,etc. I want to autoomate them but I should have a flexibility to stop that application.

Comment: You are running `/bin/bash -c "some_commands"` and therefore, those commands will become pid 1. To verify, you can run `ps aux` inside your container and search for the process with PID of 1.

Comment: if I remove -c then I get -  $ docker run --rm -ti --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/,target=/app docker_test
/bin/bash: cd /app && rm -vrf builddir && meson builddir && cd builddir && ninja docker_test && ./docker_test: No such file or directory
failed to resize tty, using default size

Comment: So, the question is here how to run my application without init 1 pid

Comment: Hmm this is actually not the use case for using docker container actually as each container should (ideally) have only 1 process running inside. You can still have it as PID 1 and run the container without `--rm` and also give it a name like `docker run --name app_name ...`. When you want to stop the application, simply just stop the container `docker stop app_name`. When you want to start the application again, run `docker start app_name`. This can also be automated.

Comment: you are correct. I accepted your answer but why you asked me to remove --rm?

Comment: It depends on your use case, and how you want to automate it. If you keep the `--rm` then once you stop the container, it will automatically be removed (which might be a good thing). Otherwise, you can create a container without `--rm` and `stop` and `start` it as and when you like :)